# onListItemClick inside a custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a custom ListView which has several TextView objects in each row. in the onListItemClick, I'd like to get the actual TextView that was clicked, but I am simply getting the LinearLayout View that contains the two TextViews.

```
class CustomList extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, R.id.label, data);
    setListAdapter(aa);
  }

  public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int index, long id){
    // I would like to access the TextView that was clicked here
    // v = LinearLayout, not the TextView that was clicked
  }
}
```

Below is res/custom_list_item.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30sp">
</TextView>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/delete_text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="X">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define an `onClickListener` for your `TextView` items.  Right now, your click listener only applies to your `CustomList` and not your `TextView` items.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out I needed to subclass `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView` to add the `onClickListener` to the `TextView` items.